# Pop up dialog is shown twice in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm using a alertdialog to show a message to the user, but when the ok button is pressed, the dialog is shown again. After pressing the ok button for the second time, that's when the dialog finally disappears.

Here is my code:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(hours) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(minutes) < 0)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Warning")
            .setMessage("The ending time cannot be earlier than the start time!")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    // continue with delete
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
             })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .show();

        }
```

**EDIT:**
The code is triggered when a user fills a ending time (in an EditText) that is earlier than the start time, using time pickers. The if clause is called in the unlock event of the EditText for the ending time/

Anybody got an idea why this is happening?

Comment: How are you triggering this code? provide more informative code

Comment: Use `dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: @jyoon Tried it, doesn't work

Comment: Debug to check if it's entering twice in the conditional block. Code looks fine.

Comment: There should be a problem with your method to check the EditText value then. Please post your EditText change listener. You can rename variables if you wish not to share them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are triggering twice the code block to show the Alert Dialogue.

So Alert Dialogue is showing one above another.

It is not related with OK button click.

There is no issues with the code snippet provided.

Comment: The code block was indeed being triggered twice because of a paramater that was used in the if clause. Now I reset the value every time the alert dialog is shown. Thanks for the help!